# get arrival/travel time of perticular route in here-api android

Tags: android, here-api

I am using android Here-sdk. I got total distance of perticular route from `MapRoute` object. So now i want to get arrival/travel time of perticular route.

Below is the code for distance. what would i do for get time from `MapRoute` object. Thanks!

```
for(int i = list_routes.size() ; i > 0 ; i--)
{
    MapRoute mapRoute = new MapRoute(list_routes.get(i-1).getRoute());
    mapRoute.setColor(color_array.get(i-1));
    mapRoute.setTrafficEnabled(true);

    // here i got total distance
    int distance = mapRoute.getRoute().getLength();

    m_map.addMapObject(mapRoute);   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
int timeInSeconds = mapRoute.getRoute().getTta(x, y).getDuration();
```

where `x` is `TrafficPenaltyMode` and `y` is subleg number. You can check the details in the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-routing-route.html#topic-apiref__gettta-route-trafficpenaltymode-int).

Comment: If i pass  `mapRoute.getRoute().getSublegCount()` as `y` value it `throw exception` of **IllegalArgumentException: subleg must be be >= 0 and less than the number of subleg(s)**

Comment: The error tells it all. Just look at what you are doing.

Comment: @Akash please read the documentation. There is a special value `WHOLE_ROUTE` you can pass there to calculate tta for the whole route.

Answer (score 2):

The documentaion link change use this instead  [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/Route.html#getTtaExcludingTraffic-int-)

the getTTa method is deprecated now, use

```
Route.getTtaIncludingTraffic(int subleg)
```

or

```
Route.getTtaExcludingTraffic(int subleg)
```

if you want the travel time for the whole route  use this value

```
Route.WHOLE_ROUTE
```

example:

```
int timeInSeconds = route.getTtaExcludingTraffic(Route.WHOLE_ROUTE).getDuration();
```